# bootstrap conflicting with font-awesome?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have installed these gems : `font-awesome-rails` and `bootstrap` (gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-rails',
    :github => 'anjlab/bootstrap-rails')

In my `application.css.scss`, I have

```
 *= require twitter/bootstrap
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

@import "font-awesome";
@import "font.css.scss";
```

where the last file contains `@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700");` The problem, is that no icon is loaded in my `html` because `fontawesome` seems not to be fetched. So I installed the `font-awesome` gem, but it didn't change anything. Could someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one in your Gemfile (outside of the assets group)? `gem 'font-awesome-rails', '4.0.1.0'`  After you bundle install, make any change (i.e. add an empty line) to your application.css.scss to get it to re-compile.

Comment: Yes I have just tried it but I still can't get get any font awesome